# Python code refactoring question. Applying functions to multiple elements

Tags: python, refactoring, list

I have code that looks something like this:

```
self.ui.foo.setEnabled(False)
self.ui.bar.setEnabled(False)
self.ui.item.setEnabled(False)
self.ui.item2.setEnabled(False)
self.ui.item3.setEnabled(False)
```

And I would like to turn it into something like this:

```
items = [foo,bar,item,item2,item3]
for elm in items:
    self.ui.elm.setEnabled(False)
```

But obviously just having the variables in the list with out the 'self.ui' part is invalid, and I would rather not type out 'self.ui' for every element in the list, because that really isn't to much better.  How could I rewrite my first code to make it something like what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grab the object to have the function called on it by its attribute name using the built-in [getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
items = ['foo', 'bar', 'item', 'item2', 'item3']
for elm in items:
    getattr(self.ui, elm).setEnabled(False)
```

Answer (score -3):

You could try something like:

```
items = [foo,bar,item,item2,item3]
ui = self.ui
for elm in items:
    ui.elm.setEnabled(False)
```

Comment: When adding just the items foo,bar to the list items, you are referencing variables that do not exist.  self.ui.foo != foo