# How do you update the values of multiple variables in a loop in Python?

Tags: python, scope

I would like to do something like the following:

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3

l = [x,y,z]

for variable in l:
    variable += 2

print x
print y
print z
```

Unfortunately, when I print x,y and z after this block, the values have remained at 1,2 and 3 respectively.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150856/python-code-refactoring-question-applying-functions-to-multiple-elements) related question, but the solution there doesn't solve my problem.

Is there a neat and efficient way to perform the same action to multiple variables like I have tried to above?

P.S. I am using Python 2.6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cant change x,y,z like this. x,y,z are integers and they are immutable. You need to make new variables.

```
x, y, z = (v + 2 for v in l)
```

Comment: After playing around with the solutions, it may be useful to note that you can replace v + 2 here with some_func(v) and apply a function to all parts of your list.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `variable` is scoped to the `for` loop.

If you were to write

```
for variable in my_list:
    variable += 2
    print variable
```

you'd see the values you expect.  But, once you get to the next `for` loop iteration, variable is forgotten and replaced with the next list value.

What you want to do is:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
   list[i] += 2
```

which will give the effect you want.  This is because it's the actual item in the list that's being incremented by 2, not a local copy inside in the for loop.

Comment: I think that the OP wants `x`, `y`, and `z` to be updated, in which case the problem is that `int` is an immutable type in python. If mutable types were being considered, like `dict`s or `list`s, the changes would persist.

Comment: Whether the integer value referenced by `list[i]` in my example is mutating or being replaced by the increment operator isn't particularly relevant to the OP's confusion.  His or her problem arises from the belief that the local `variable` maintains a reference to the list item, which it does not.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. `variable` does reference the list element, in my mind (you can check this by seeing that the id of the loop variable matches the id of the list element). If the list element is immutable, the following assignment operator acts as like a copy. If it is mutable, then it acts like a reference, and the value is mutated. So if Python `int`s were mutable, then the OP's code would have worked.

Comment: After looking at it again, I agree with you.  I wasn't clear that the OP was looking at the original x, y, z variables, rather than the list.

Answer (score 1):

look into [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3

l = [x,y,z]

l = map(lambda x: x+2, l)  # [3, 4, 5]
```

You are essentially "mapping" one list to another, with the modification for each element defined by your lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like below using list comprehension and then assign the values returned to the variables `x`, `y`, `z`

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 2
>>> z = 3
>>> lst = [x,y,z]
>>> [i+2 for i in lst]
[3, 4, 5]
>>> x, y, z = [i+2 for i in lst]
>>> x
3
>>> y
4
>>> z
5
```

As said in the below comment , don't use `list` as a variable name. `list` is  a special function used for creating a list.

Comment: List are mutable, i think.

Comment: The problem isn't that lists are immutable (they're mutable), but that integers are *immutable*.

Comment: Yep, so this code wont affect x,y and z, and this is what OP is after.

Comment: nit: don't encourage the use of `list` as a variable name ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension:

```
 print [variable+2 for variable in list]
```

'variable' in your case is local variable and it's scope is diminished once you exit the for loop. It's better to avoid the list name as `list` as it's in-built

Comment: This wont change x,y and z.

Comment: You could catch the return value and re-assign as `list=[variable+2 for variable in list]` to change the values in the list and not x,y and z.

Comment: You could use list unpacking to re-assign to `x`, `y`, and `z`: `x,y,z = [variable + 2 for variable in list]`.

Comment: I was using the name list just for this example for clarity. In hindsight I guess it made it less clear!

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's better to store the bunch of things you want to manipulate in a list

```
xyz = [1, 2, 3]

for i in range(len(xyz)):
    xyz[i] += 2
```

Sometimes (but you should look for other ways first) `exec` is a good (but be careful if you are exec'ing input under control of a user)

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 2
>>> z = 3
>>> for variable in ['x', 'y', 'z']:
...     exec '{} += 2'.format(variable)
... 
>>> x, y, z
(3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet seen an answer mention *mutability* vs. *immutability*, which is **why** you're seeing this behavior. It's a really important concept in Python, since it sort of replaces notions of "pass by reference" and "pass by value" that other languages have. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) for an in-depth treatment, but I'll give a quick illustrative example here.

In Python, an `int` is immutable. That means that the *value* of an integer cannot be changed. On the other hand, `list`s and `dict`s are mutable, meaning they can be changed.

Consider these two cases:

```
x = (1,2,3,4,5)

for y in x:
    y += 1

print x
```

This prints:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Here we tried to update `int`s, which are immutable. Hence after the `for`-loop, `x` remains unchanged. You can sort of think that at each iteration of the loop, the current entry of `x` is *copied* to `y`, and this copy is changed, not the entry itself. Now let's change a mutable type:

```
x = ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])

for y in x:
    y += [42]

print x
```

which prints:

```
([1, 42], [2, 42], [3, 42], [4, 42], [5, 42])
```

We see that the elements of `x` *have* changed. This is precisely because the elements of `x` are lists, and lists are mutable.

By the way, you might notice that the container used in both cases was a tuple, which is immutable. You can mutate mutable objects inside of a tuple -- no problem there -- you just can't mutate the tuple itself and the references it contains.

After all of this I still haven't really answered your question, but the answer's sort of implied by the above: you shouldn't store these objects separately, but in a list. Then all of the list comprehension answers given make sense and do what you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want to change the values of X, Y, and Z or the contents of the list. So here are some options:

```
# as pointed out by the comments this is a bad idea. It violates Pythonic principles
# and your outcomes may be less consistent than you would like
f = locals()
for n in ['x','y','z']:
    f[n] += 2 # modifies the values of the variables
```

You could also be trying to get a new list which has all updated values. For that use map:

```
l = map(lambda x: x+2, [x,y,z])
'''
you could also do: 
    l = [x,y,z]
    l = map(lambda x: x+2, l)
'''
```

Or, you could be trying to update the values of the `l` list:

```
l = [x,y,z]
for idx, val in enumerate(l):
    l[idx] = val + 2
```

Comment: You forgot about the disclaimer: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: Assigning to `locals()` only works when `global() == locals()`